# Read string as array<string> in hive sql

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am working on hive, reading some fields from JSON string through hive query. One field in JSON string is actually an array of string but stored as string like `{... , 'arrText' : '["a","b","c"]',... }`

I want to read this string as array of string in hive query itself.

```
hive (joshua)> 
              > select some_function('["a","b","c"]');
OK
["a","b","c"]
Time taken: 0.134 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Can I have something (hive built in) in place of `some_function` & get it done rather than writing UDF for it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it without udf is use some pre-defined hive functions like split, regex extract etc

```
select split(regexp_extract('["a","b","c"]','^\\["(.*)\\"]$',1),'","');
=> ["a","b","c"]
```

Even it can handle intermediate commas

```
select split(regexp_extract('["a","b,c","d"]','^\\["(.*)\\"]$',1),'","');
=> ["a","b,c","d"]
```

Hop it helps